# RSS-reader in Ajax: Help with code, what's wrong/missing?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, rss

I'm learning Ajax currently, and I use "Sams Teach Yourself Ajax in 10 minutes".
I've learnt much, and understand Ajax basically. The book writes code-examples and go through the code bit by bit to explain what each bit does.
However. In this code there is something wrong written by the author, and I don't know what..

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>An Ajax RSS Headline Reader</title>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
try {
req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* e.g. Firefox */
} catch(e) {
  try {
  req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  /* some versions IE */
  } catch (e) {
    try {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    /* some versions IE */
    } catch (E) {
      req = false;
    }
  }
}
return req;
}
var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();

function getRSS() {
  var myurl = 'rssproxy.php?feed=';
  var myfeed = document.form1.feed.value;
    myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);
    // cache buster

   var modurl = myurl+escape(myfeed)+"&rand="+myRand;
   http.open("GET", modurl, true);
   http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
   http.send(null);
}
function useHttpResponse() {
   if (http.readyState == 4) {
    if(http.status == 200) {
       // first remove the childnodes
       // presently in the DM
       while (document.getElementById('news') .hasChildNodes())
      {
document.getElementById('news').removeChild(document .getElementById('news').firstChild);
      }
      var titleNodes = http.responseXML .getElementsByTagName("title");
      var descriptionNodes = http.responseXML .getElementsByTagName("description");
      var linkNodes = http.responseXML .getElementsByTagName("link");
      for(var i =1;i<titleNodes.length;i++)
      {
        var newtext = document .createTextNode(titleNodes[i] .childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        var newpara = document.createElement('p');
        var para = document.getElementById('news') .appendChild(newpara);
        newpara.appendChild(newtext);
        newpara.className = "title";

        var newtext2 = document .createTextNode(descriptionNodes[i] .childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        var newpara2 = document.createElement('p');
        var para2 = document .getElementById('news').appendChild(newpara2);
        newpara2.appendChild(newtext2);
        newpara2.className = "descrip";
        var newtext3 = document .createTextNode(linkNodes[i] .childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        var newpara3 = document.createElement('p');

        var para3 = document.getElementById('news') .appendChild(newpara3);
        newpara3.appendChild(newtext3);
        newpara3.className = "link";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<body>
<center>
<h3>An Ajax RSS Reader</h3>
<form name="form1">
URL of RSS feed: <input type="text" name="feed" size="50" value="http://"><input
 type="button" onClick="getRSS()" value="Get Feed"><br><br>
<div id="news" class="displaybox"> <h4>Feed Titles</h4></div>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

and rssproxy.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$mysession = curl_init($_GET['feed']);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$out = curl_exec($mysession);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $out;
curl_close($mysession);
?>
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me!

I only want to know what's wrong with this code, and not get links to other Ajax RSS-tutorials, unless it's exactly the same codes (without the malfunctions of course)..

Comment: According to the TOC of this book there is a section "Online Resources and _Errata_" in the chapter "Introduction". Did you check those resources?

Comment: Hi!
The section says:
"Visit the Sams Publishing website at www.samspublishing.com where you can download the example code and obtain further information and details of errata."

I've downloaded the example code now, and it's exactly the same as the one I've written above. And I don't think any of my settings is wrong, because all the other script/codes works perfectly..

Thanks for the comment though! (:

Answer (score 1):

First let's test if the php script can fetch and deliver an rss feed at all

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// $mysession = curl_init($_GET['feed']);
$mysession = curl_init('http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/index.rss');


curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$out = curl_exec($mysession);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $out;
curl_close($mysession);
?>
```

Just invoke it from the browser and check the output.
If that works install and use a client-side script debugger. E.g. for firefox use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/1843). Javascript errors will show up in the console tab.

Comment: hum.. Seems like the curl-exstension isn't enabled..
I'm using xampp and has edited (removed the comment on extension=php_curl.dll) php.ini and php5.ini in the php-folder, but it still not working.. any suggestions have to enable it?

Comment: `echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` tells you which php.ini you have to edit. Could be a php.ini within the apache/bin directory (depending on the version of xampp you're using)

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong in XML content. Maybe missing **<link>** tag.

Comment: I don't think so, because it doesn't show a xml-file I've made myself either, with everyone of the requested tags..

Thanks anyway! (: